# In Asp.Net MVC, why is it that ApplicationUser is always null in my code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to initialize _applicationUser object in the constructor

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private ApplicationUser _applicationUser;

    public ManageController()
    {
        _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _applicationUser = new ApplicationUser();

        // the _applicationUser below is always null,
        // Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

        _applicationUser = _dbContext.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        ViewBag.ProfilePhoto = new ProfilePhotoViewModel
        {
            ProfilePhoto = _applicationUser.ProfilePhoto
        };
    }

    public ActionResult Account()
    {
        _applicationUser = _dbContext.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        ViewBag.ProfilePhoto = new ProfilePhotoViewModel
        {
            ProfilePhoto = _applicationUser.ProfilePhoto
        };
    }
```

But if I comment the _applicationUser and the ViewBag in the constructor then browse directly to /Manage/Account everything works fine

```
_applicationUser = _dbContext.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

does work in Account() but I don't know why it wouldn't work in the constructor area

Comment: What does `User.Identity.GetUserId()` return? Debugging 101, always ensure everything has the value you think it should have.

Comment: Because the httpcontext is not available yet at the time the controller is initialized. And since the httpcontext is what hold the user then user is not available as yet either

Comment: @Nkosi - interesting...wondering how am I getting context and user claims in my custom authorize attribute! Also in my base controller constructor. `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request context is not available in the constructor so there is no current identity/user.

Comment: Are you sure? What made you think that request context is not available in the constructor?

Comment: @Developer, the httpcontext is not available yet at the time the controller is initialized. And since the httpcontext is what hold the user then user is not available as yet either

Comment: But it's not wise to query db in every action for the user data right, that's why i need to set in in the constructor so that it's available for the rest of the methods. Any idea how can i do it in constructor?

Comment: @Nkosi - interesting...wondering how am I getting context and user claims in my custom authorize attribute! Also in my base controller constructor. IMO `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` should be available. May be the controller context is null...

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the identity name from
`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. Do not get confused with `HttpContext` of `Controller` and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`; `Controller.HttpContext` - controller context will not be available in the constructor as others mentioned.